# Good practice - type convertion

Tags: types, string-conversion

My application reads data from file and instantiates objects with that data. I can edit and create new object and set the attributes. My problem is with attribute "date" and its type. I don't know if I should convert String date to Date type? I don't write the data neither to a file or a db on exit. They exist just during app lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you, but if you'll be manipulating it and/or working with it a lot, `Date` will help a lot. If it's going to save you lines of code, go ahead and use it. If it's just trivial, you can decide which way to go. Still, either way `Date` would be preferred -- it just may not be worth changing if you'd have a huge amount to change.

Answer (score 1):

Like @PhillipSchmidt said, if you aren't going to be doing much with that date string, I wouldn't bother converting it.

For example, if you are just retrieving the date string to display it to the user, you would be converting it from a `String` to a `Date` (with appropriate error handling), and then back to a `String` object. That's two unnecessary conversions if your plan is to just display the date as it is.

If, however, you plan to manipulate that date or format it in a specific manner, it would probably be best to convert it to a `Date` object. There are a number of very useful options made available to `Date` objects that allow you to format it, get specific properties (year, month, day, etc), get the time since epoch (useful for sorting purposes, among other things), or change the date (add a month, subtract a day, etc).

There is no 'right' answer, it's mostly dependent on what exactly you want to do with the date.

Comment: Wwhat about situation when user is asked to type the date? I need to check its format and then date is used just to be displayed.

Comment: If you are validating user input, again, you could use a String and execute a regex on it to ensure it matches your acceptable date format, or attempt converting it into a date and catch the error if there is a bad format. Up to you really. 

If this is for a GUI or web based application, you could use the available date input components that will construct the Date object for you and ensure it is a valid date.